# Getting correct string ouput, however I'm also getting an undesired null ouput as well

Tags: java

This is outputting 'nullsd87xc8' or some other random password but it keeps putting out null before the random letters as well.

```
import java.util.*;
public class PassGen {
public static String randomPassword;
private static Scanner kb;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This program will generate a random password");
        System.out.println("Enter desired password length");
        kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int passLeng = kb.nextInt();
        char[] passData = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*".toCharArray();
        Random rand = new Random();


        for (int i=1;i<=passLeng;i++) {
            int random = rand.nextInt(passData.length-1);
            randomPassword = randomPassword + Character.toString(passData[random]);


        }
        System.out.println(randomPassword);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

randomPassword is null to begin with. Then you add characters to it. Change

```
public static String randomPassword;
```

to

```
public static String randomPassword = "";
```

Comment: That fixed it. you da best.

Comment: @ThomasMcSwain It is customary to mark a correct answer as such. That way people don't have look at the question only to find out that it's been answered.

Comment: Yeah sorry It said I had to wait a bit to actually mark it correct and I just went back to it now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not initializing the string `randomPassword` before you use it. Line 3 declares the string, giving it memory space but no value. The output that you are getting is not actually random characters appended to the word null, it's telling you the memory address containing that string, i.e. `null @ 0x3333333`. This is Java's way of saying it is null, but because of Java's methods for storing string objects you still have a memory address displayed. Change line 3 to read `public static String randomPassword = "";` and you should be in business.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `""` to `randomPassword`

```
public static String randomPassword="";
```